# Form Login and HTTP Authorization header

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-security, http-headers, authorization

I was checking the HTML code for the default form login page of Spring Security using Spring Boot. Apparently, there are 3 fields in the form (username, password and a hidden  CSRF token) and it is a POST request.

I assumed that the HTTP request will not use Authorization header in this case - I have not seen any JavaScript code or something like that which encodes the username:password combination into a Base64 encoded string and puts it into HTTP Authorization header.

But when I checked the Google Chrome Developer tools Inspect, I find that the browser is actually sending the Authorization header with Basic scheme (with username and password Base64 encoded). Also the post body of the HTTP request again contained all the 3 fields (username, password and CSRF token).

How does this happen? Will the browser automatically recognize that this is as a login form and automatically create the Authorization header?

Please find my configuration below:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                //.httpBasic();
                .formLogin()
                
                ;
        
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    }
```

Please note that I am testing using Form login.

Comment: what is your spring security config?

Comment: Updated the question with the configuration code. Kindly see the question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I couldn't reproduce your issue. It would have been much confusing for me if it did
- When I put back `httpBasic()` in config, as I expected I see `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"` in the server response, which makes the browser to create the login popup and Send the `Authorization` header on submission.

  [image]
- Do you see any such response header before the login form is displayed?

Comment: You are right; I cound not reproduce the issue. Form login expects a session (JSESSIONID value must be set). I think there must have been a mistake in my observation (maybe I have noted the BasicAuth scheme instead of Form Login). Thanks  a bunch! Accepting your answer.